# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID command not found when using shell to call aws cli passing environment var fail:

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

When I use Environment Variable to call aws cli in work terminal directly it will success:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx AWS_REGION=xxx aws elb describe-load-balancers --output json --debug
```

But if in shell, I first setup AWS_KEY_PAIR then execute the same command, it will returns to me `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx: command not found`
My shell script looks like this:

```
function test(){
AWS_KEY_PAIR="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY} AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}"

${AWS_KEY_PAIR} aws elb describe-load-balancers --output json --debug }
```

Could anyone tell me why it success if I run first command directly in work terminal but fail in shell script? Is the AWS_KEY_PAIR can't be setup like this?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in the way you modify the environment:

> **`man bash` :** The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described above in PARAMETERS.  These assignment statements affect only  the  environment  seen  by
> that command.

This means that if a variable exists, you can have it temporarily modified for a single command. Eg.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
echo $FOO
$ FOO="hello world"
$ echo $FOO
hello world
$ FOO="hello universe" ./test.sh
hello universe
$ echo $FOO
hello world
```

There you see that during the execution of `FOO="hello universe" ./test.sh` the variable `FOO` is temporarily modified. This is exactly what you do during execution of your command on the command line.

In your script however, you attempt something different. You assign the assignment of your script to a variable and then try to "execute this".

```
$ BAR="FOO=hello"
$ echo $BAR
FOO=hello
$ $BAR
bash: FOO=hello: command not found...
```

As you see, it tries to execute the command `FOO=hello` which is not a command but actually a string you try to execute. It is similar to typing `$ "FOO=hello"`. So you can now imagine that

```
$ $BAR ./test.sh
```

will also not execute.

There is an [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) workaround here using `eval`, but [`eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

> **`man bash` :**  `eval [arg ...]`
>
> The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of `eval`.  If there are no args, or  only  null  arguments, `eval` returns `0`.

```
$ BAR="FOO=hello"
$ echo $BAR
FOO=hello
$ eval $BAR
$ echo $FOO
hello
$ FOO="hello world"
$ eval $BAR ./test.sh
hello
```

The latter examples are exactly what you try to attempt in your function `test()`. You assign your *variable declaration* to the variable `AWS_KEY_PAIR` and then execute `aws` with the modified environment `${AWS_KEY_PAIR}`, but this will not work as `AWS_KEY_PAIR` is nothing more then a long string. You can thus fix it by placing `eval` in front of it, or by typing the full key pair out as

```
function test(){
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}           \
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}    \
   AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}                   \
   aws elb describe-load-balancers --output json --debug
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It works for me!